# DKIM : Which domain is considered?

Tags: email, dkim

DKIM verifies the domain of an e-mail sender, but... What "domain" does it check?

```
The "domain" of the MAILFROM field of the SMTP envelope ?
The "domain" of the FROM header of the message ?
The "domain" of the SENDER header of the message ?
A "domain" that can be chosen arbitrarily?
```

I can not find a source that explicitly explains that. Would you know one?

Thank you very much,

Niles

Answer (score 1):

DKIM doesn't verify the sender, it verifies the integrity of the message and parts of the header.

The domain in the dkim signature is a domain that took some part in the delivery of the message.

The founding document is [RFC6376](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6376)

Comment: A very good answer. To give some more details:  The DKIM signature is created by the sender (mailserver) using a private key. It contains:  "d=mydomain.com" to refer to how to find a public key to decrypt the signing,  "h= < a list of headers etc" describing the part of the headers (or headers + body) that are signed. The receiving mailserver then uses the public key to calculate if ANY of the items listed in "h="  has been modified in the transfer.  So to answer Your first question: it check the FROM:, TO: Subject: etc, but not the MAILFROM (which is not part of the header but the Envelope

Comment: Excuse me, I misspoke.

I wanted to know where the "domain" value came from in the "d = domain" tag. FROM ? SENDER ? OTHER ?

Comment: Its usually a MTA (mail transfer agent aka mail server), that  processes/forwards the message.

Comment: The domain in the DKIM signature can be anything. Its obviously something that is administratively easy as the public key in DNS needs to match the private RSA key on the MTA server.